# QEMU stuck keys

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, qemu, troubleshooting

My keyboard locks up sometimes when I press CTRL related keyboard combinations, for example CTRL+C, CTRL+V etc. One behaviour is that the "C" key seems to be stuck so it writes "cccccccccc" etc. into the editor until I interrupt it by pressing another combination. 
Sometimes I can get the stuck keys unstuck by just pressing random combinations in the hope to "free" it. Othertimes I need to restart the VM which is annoying.

my setup:

- host is a Ubuntu 21.04
- emulated OS is a Arch based Manjaro which is up to date

Answer (score 0):

changing the input handling by disabling repeated input in the input settings of Ubuntu seems to get partially rid of the issue.

https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/455